# TypeError: Data type not understood, numpy.zeros

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, typeerror, zero

I am getting an error while running my code.  The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/penguin/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/Recipes.py", line 
153, in <module>
newRatios = np.zeros(count,count)
TypeError: data type not understood

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is:

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
newRatios = np.zeros(count,count)
print(newRatios)
for ep in XDF['EmailPrefix']:
   for ep2 in XDF['EmailPrefix']:
       if count1 != count2:
           newRatios[count1,count2] = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(ep,ep2)
       else:
           newRatios[count1,count2] = None
       count2 += 1
   count1 += 1
   if(count1 == 2500):
       print('Halfway')

print(newRatios)
```

The variable count represents a integer value of about 5000.  I apologize I can only give code snippets instead of the entire file, but I am not allowed to disclose the full file.

Not really sure why I'm getting this error, I have tried a few different methods of setting up numpy zeros array and setting up a 2D matrix.  Please note that I import numpy as np so thats why its called np.  I am using python3, if you have any other suggestions for setting up a 2D array and accessing it better than I am here that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass in a tuple. Try `np.zeros((count, count))`.

Further documentation on this method available here:  **https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html**

Answer (score 1):

Use a sequence of ints:

```
newRatios = np.zeros((count,count))
```

Shape parameter of `zeros` accepts int or sequence of ints. Refer [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html).

Answer (score 0):

`np.zeros` accepts an iterable as the shape argument. You need to pass your arguments as `np.zeros((count,count))`. Notice the extra parenthesis. What you're currently doing is passing in `count` as the `shape` and then passing in `count` again as a datatype. It doesn't recognize the datatype that `count` represents, hence the error.